# why should I click twice to trigger the event?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="search_on" id="search-item">
    <span class="text">one</span>
</div>
<ul class="search_item" style="display: none;">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search-item .text').toggle(function () {
        $('ul.search_item').show();
    }, function () {
        $('ul.search_item').hide();
    });

    $('.search_item li a').click(function(){
        $('ul.search_item').hide();
        $('#search-item .text').text($(this).text());
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

When I click the `a` link, the above value changes to two as expected. But the value which is from the changed I should have clicked twice, the bottom `ul` list will show. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggle` event method is deprecated, you can use show/hide `toggle` instead:

```
$('#search-item .text').click(function() {
    $('ul.search_item').toggle();
});
```

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kH36R/

Comment: Yo ++1 `:)` and a **demo** for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kH36R/ ; Hope you will not mind me adding a demo in your post, nice one braver!

Answer (score 1):

**OR** try this: http://jsfiddle.net/sM7Tn/

you can do `$('ul.search_item').is(':visible'))` is visible check and rest will work like a rocket `:)`

Hope it fits the cause B-)

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-item .text').click(function() {
        if (!$('ul.search_item').is(':visible')) 
            $('ul.search_item').show();
        else 
            $('ul.search_item').hide();

    });

    $('.search_item li a').click(function() {
        $('ul.search_item').hide();
        $('#search-item .text').text($(this).text());
        return false;

    });
});​
```